# Runtime error in Ideone but works fine in codeblocks

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I tested this code on codeblocks and it is working fine but when i run this on Ideone i get runtime error and SIGSEGV error on OJ. I read online that SIGSEGV error is caused due to restricted memory access. But if it is doing so why isn't codeblocks complaining......

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    int t, i, j, k, x, temp;
    int num1[10000], num2[10000];
    char c;
    bool f = true;
    cin >> t;

    while (t--)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        {
            num1[i] = 0;
            num2[i] = 0;
        }
        i = 0;
        j = 0;
        while (!isspace(c = getchar()))
            num1[i++] = c - '0';
        while (!isspace(c = getchar()))
            num2[j++] = c - '0';
        x = i > j ? i : j;
        temp = 0;
        for (k = 0; k < x; k++)
        {
            i = temp + num1[k] + num2[k];
            if (f)
            {
                if (i % 10 != 0)
                {
                    f = false;
                    cout << i % 10;
                }
            }
            else cout << i % 10;
            temp = i / 10;
        }
        if (temp != 0)
            cout << temp;
        cout << endl;
        f = true;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: can run it without any problems http://ideone.com/o0VUeS

Comment: @vsoftco try with an input 1 24 1 as...http://ideone.com/tHgh8a

Comment: No, but because this is basically a code dump for which it seems you haven't taken the time to narrow down to a specific piece of code or given us useful information that can help us reproduce the problem ourselves.

Comment: What's the input? If you run this with no input, then you'll get a garbage value for `t`. If that's not zero (or if you do have input, but the value of `t` is too large, or there's no space after the final number), then you'll keep reading `EOF` and incrementing `i` and `j` for ever, until you go off the end of the arrays and (probably) cause a segfault. Always check your input.

Comment: @MikeSeymour i tried with input 1 24 1 http://ideone.com/tHgh8a

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This:

```
while (!isspace(c = getchar()))
```

will keep going until it finds a space character. If there's no space after the final input value, then `getchar()` will return `EOF`, which you'll truncate to `char` and pass to `isspace`, giving undefined behaviour. The chances are that `isspace` will return false, and you'll loop forever, off the end of your fixed size array, until you reach unaddressable memory and cause a segmentation fault.

Always check input before using it. You'll also have big problems if there's no input, since you don't check whether `t` was successfully read.

Comment: thanx for pointing that out....another problem i think is that i am using getchar() with sync to cstdio disabled.